# byte array to Image throw IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have an image loaded as a byte[] and I need to save it as a jpeg image. I have attempted to save it, but I give me an IllegalArgumentException.

```
 private String saveProcessedImage(byte[] imageInBytes, String surface) throws IOException {

    String savePath = imageSavePath+"\\"+surface+"-"+ UUID.randomUUID()+".jpg";

    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInBytes);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(in);
    ImageIO.write(img,"jpg",new File(savePath));
    img.flush();
    in.close();
    return savePath;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
    at com.abc.def.agent.imaging.ImageProcessJobBroker.saveProcessedImage(ImageProcessJobBroker.java:80)
    at com.abc.def.agent.imaging.ImageProcessJobBroker.processFrontAndBack(ImageProcessJobBroker.java:48)
    at com.abc.def.agent.imaging.TestBroker.main(TestBroker.java:9)
```

What I notice in here is BuffredImage `img` is null when it gets called ImageIO.write() even though the byte[] and InputStream `in` exist.

Call to the above saveProcessedImage() method:

```
frontImagePath = saveProcessedImage(jniImageProcAgent.getProcessedBinaryImage(frontImageFileName), "front");
```

Here is the JNI signature of the method:

```
public native int GetProcessedBinaryImage(ZvImage srcImage, ZvImage dest, String[] errorMsg, boolean isFront);
```

method that does the jin call:

```
public byte[] getProcessedBinaryImage(String filePath) throws IOException {
        File imagePath = new File(filePath);
        BufferedImage bufImg = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
        WritableRaster raster = bufImg.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte imgdata = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        ComponentSampleModel csm = (ComponentSampleModel) raster.getSampleModel();

        ZvImage zvSrcImg = new ZvImage();
        ZvImage zvDestImg = new ZvImage();
        zvSrcImg.width = bufImg.getWidth();
        zvSrcImg.height = bufImg.getHeight();
        zvSrcImg.bpp = 24;
        zvSrcImg.stride = csm.getScanlineStride();
        zvSrcImg.data = imgdata.getData();
        String[] msg = new String[1];

        int status = GetProcessedBinaryImage(zvSrcImg, zvDestImg, msg, true);


        if ((zvDestImg.nativeData != null) && (0 == status)) return zvDestImg.nativeData;
        return null;
    }
```

ZvImage dto used to transfer data:

```
public class ZvImage {
        public int width;
        public int height;
        public int bpp;
        public int stride;
        public byte[] data;
        public byte[] nativeData;

        public void setNativeData(byte[] nativeData) {
            this.nativeData = nativeData;
        }

        public byte[] getData() {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

What am I doning wrong in here? Appreciate your support.

Comment: How do you load byte into `imageInBytes` ?

Comment: According to ImageIO.read() method specification "If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned." - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream)

Comment: @ortis : imageInBytes are loading via a JNI call

Comment: @Divers : thanks, but im bit confused about this

Comment: Show is the code that load the byte. There is probably something wrong in here. Why use JNI btw ?

Comment: JNI snippet added. had to use JNI since I'm using an external native library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the byte[], problem was with the way I created my image, I changed the parameters and returned it from the method where JNI methods are called.

```
//region -- Code stub to create the buffered image --
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(zvDestImg.width, zvDestImg.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(zvDestImg.nativeData, zvDestImg.nativeData.length);
        SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, zvDestImg.width, zvDestImg.height, 1, zvDestImg.stride, new int[]{0});
        Raster raster2 = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
        result.setData(raster2);
        //endregion
```